# Search by multiple fields Laravel and Elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

for example, I indexed an object, the date I have more fields.
How can I search for multiple fields in elasticsearch

```
data":"{\"id\": 1, \"type\": \"room\", \"title\": \"asdasdasdsadasd\", \"post_code\": \"627155\", \"created_at\": \"2021-09-17T11:18:33.000000Z\", \"updated_at\": \"2021-09-17T11:18:33.000000Z\", \"description\": \"asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsaasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsadasdsad\"}
```

And right now I'm doing the search

```
$responses = Utils::all([$client->post('http://es:9200/indexes/_search',
            ['body' => json_encode(
                [
                    "query" => [
                        "term" => [
                            "data" => $q
                        ]
                    ],
                   
                ]
            )])
        ])->wait();
```

How could I search for multiple values and access them?
I could do ex `data.description =asdsad` in query

Comment: you can combine these using bool and must/should

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to look for a text description ... no bool

Comment: bool is way to combine query .{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
       {
        "term" : { "title" : "xyz" }
       } ,
       {
        "term" : { "description" : "abc" }
       }
      ]   
    }
  }
} https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html